# List.retainAll() not working as expected (grails 2.3.9)

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm almost certainly doing something wrong or misunderstanding List.retainAll().

I have two lists that are equal (size() ==1), yet when I call list1.retainAll(list2), list 1 becomes empty.

Code:

```
List<DomainObject> list1 = someService.getData()
List<DomainObject> list2 = someService.getOtherData()
log.info("Equal: ${list1.equals(list2)}") 
boolean changed = list1.retainAll(list2)
log.info("Changed: ${changed}")
log.info("list1 empty: ${list1.isEmpty()}")
```

Log shows:

```
Equal: true
Changed: true
list1 empty: true
```

I...  don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I've run tests with more generic objects (the actual domain object is fairly complex, but implements equals/hashcode correctly) and retainAll worked as expected.

I'm not even sure what specific question I should be asking...  Are there conditions I'm missing where equals() can return true but retainAll() fails?

Comment: Can you show your `equals` and `hashCode` implementation - in the presence of lazy-loading proxies there are some things you have to be _extremely_ careful about in an `equals` implementation, more so than usual.

Comment: I continued to bang on it and eventually got down to comparing the first element of each `List` which turned out to not be `equal` (though it baffled me that the lists evaulated as `equal` when the first element did not.  The equals() method was using `if(getClass() != o.class) return false` which was failing because o.class was a `javaassist` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully to help someone else down the line, and this is something I should have known and had run into before.

```
list1.equals(list2) //true, one element per list
list1.get(0).id == list2.get(0).id //true, same DB object
list1.get(0).equals(list2.get(0))  //false...  ?!
```

The reason was equals() was implemented starting with:

```
equals() {  
    if(getClass() != o.class) return false
}
```

getClass() was returning `DomainObject` but `o.class` (or `o.getClass()`) was returning `javaassist__blahblah`.

I replaced the check with

```
if(!(o instanceof DomainObject)) return false
```

Not sure if that's the cleanest way to do class checking in equals, for some reason I was of the impression that `instanceof` was slow.